# PHP UFT8 Encoding Internet Explorer Problems

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am facing the following problem:
Currently, I am creating a web application using the Yii2 framework for PHP running on an apache server. My web application is fully functional on Gooogle Chrome but on Internet Explorer I am facing the problem, that UTF8 econded turkish special characters are not displayed nor readable for drop down menus. The menus remain empty once a selection containing special characters is made.

I have created dynamical dropdown menus which read values from a MySQL database table. In this table, values in columns are saved in the turkish language containing special characters and collation is set to utf-8.

The header charsets of the PHP framework and also metadata of the webpage are all set to utf-8 but Internet Explorer seems to struggle with the encoding.

My code for the dropdown menus is the following:

```
<div class="feedback-view">

 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

  <p><?php

      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_feedback';
      $feedbacks = app\models\Feedback::findBySql($sql)->all();
      $list = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($feedbacks, 'name', 'name');
      echo $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList($list,   [
                                     'style'=>'width:300px',
                                     'prompt'=>'--Name select--',
                                     'class' => 'form-field',
                                     'onchange'=>'$.get("'.Yii::$app-
  >request->baseUrl.'" + "/index.php?r=feedback/test&name=" + $(this).val(),
                                                       function(data){

 $("#feedback_id").html(data);

                                                       }
                                        );'
                                      ]);

      ?>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </p>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Any hints or recommendations / tips would be highly appreciated as I am really stuck with this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the collation utf-8-general?

Comment: Please show a live example, this is rather impossible to debug otherwise I think.

Comment: Yes indeed the collation is utf-8-general. I also changed it to utf8-turkish or other without any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php this package and formatting utf8. Before I was using a different package designed for SQL which did not work for the character encoding containing the special letters.